# Convert a number to another

Tags: php, numberformatter

So I have this little problem.
I have a form where you can enter a number, it can be in European format, with comma as decimal (,), or American with the decimal point (.).

Knowing this, how can I convert the number format from the European American format? And the American format leave it unchanged?

I tried using this formula but the result is wrong.

```
$american = '12.5';
$european = '12,5';

$locale = 'it_IT.utf8';
setlocale ('LC_NUMERIC', $locale);
$fmt = new NumberFormatter ($locale, NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
$american = $ fmt->parse($american);
$european = $ fmt->parse($europen);

response

$american = 125
$european = 12.5
```

Where is the problem?

php ver. 5.4.10

Comment: you have missed an `a` out of `$europen`, whether that's relevant or not.

Comment: $stringFormatted = str_replace(',', '.', $inputstring); Shouldn't be much harder then that. Is that what you want?

Comment: No I want implement internationalization in my application, i want convert number in trasparent way, then insert it in a mysql table

Answer (score 2):

try following code:

```
$american = '12.5';
$european = '12,5';

$locale = 'en_US.utf8';
$fmt = new NumberFormatter ($locale, NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
$american = $fmt->parse($american);

$locale = 'it_IT.utf8';
$fmt = new NumberFormatter ($locale, NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
$european = $fmt->parse($european);
```

Get the desired result?

Comment: $american = 125
$european = 12.5

Comment: Can be a problem with ICU?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't better to use [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) instead?

Comment: True, but the number can come in european or american format, then i convert it with NumberFormatter function, the number can be EU 1.234.567,89 or US 1,234,567.89.